# Rep Flair Incorrect

Tags: support, reputation, area-51, flair, combined-flair

I'm looking at my flair and I see a huge increase in my total rep value (about +300). I'm not quite sure I got 300 rep total two days ago. The problem started yesterday. My flair started to look like this:
[image]

4k, not too shabby for a new user like me (member for SE for six months). But when I look at my total rep count at Area 51:

[image]

I'm at 3,696 rep, rounded to 3,700 rep. That's literally a 300 rep difference! This has to be a bug because rep flair is rounded to the hundreds. Thus my flair should show 3.7k, not 4k. So why is my flair showing me the wrong rep count total for my entire SE account (4k instead of 3.7k)?

Note: Flair only shows total rep for accounts with ***200 or more rep***.

Comment: @Tim sure about that? I can still see the difference and doubt it's caching, see my comment on the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind my question! I figured out my mistake!

Seemingly, the Area 51 rep score is still caching, so it doesn't recognize all the rep I accumulated from the past two to three days, which is about 300 rep. When I added all my current rep from eligible accounts/sites, it added a grand total of 3,987 rep, which is rounded to 4k.

The rep count at Area 51 should be updated in the next few hours or so.

UPDATE: Make that two months. Caching has catched up with time:

[image]

Comment: Well, the culprit is MSE, Area 51 thinks you still have 794 reputation here. I doubt it's caching, more likely synch went wrong, e.g. when a post with lots of upvotes was deleted and you lost rep due to that - there is per site "clean up" job that makes sure reputation is always correct, but it's not synching with Area 51 properly. :/

Comment: Yet another Area51 bug that will never be fixed...